# mod_rewrite trailing slash with RewriteCond

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have searched through the related mod_rewrite qustions but I can't anything specific enough so I'll post:

Heres my rule that adds a trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Only I want to exclude one specific directory eg. **/mydirectoryname/** and not add the trailing slash to anything that starts with that. Reason being its breaking some of my ajax calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another RewriteCond:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mydicrectoryname)/`

Comment: Thanks I slightly varied it but it helped :) RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/mydirectoryname/.*$)

Answer (score 2):

You can descibe that with just one condition:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^mydirectoryname(/|$)
RewriteRule ^[^\.]+[^/]$ /$0/ [R=301,L]
```