# Trailing slash 'bug' in mod_rewrite www-removal snippet

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I got a snippet to redirect all `www.domain.com` requests to `domain.com` from another SO question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately it results in an extra trailing slash:

`www.domain.com` redirects to `domain.com//` and
`www.domain.com/path/` redirects to `domain.com//path/`

Should I really add an [extra rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859536/mod-rewrite-trailing-slash-with-rewritecond) to remove the trailing slash? Or is there a problem with the above snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the slash from the third line should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Now only I have to decide whether I also want to redirect ww. or perhaps even all subdomains..